# Outlook Web Access calendar out of sync with Exchange / Outlook

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-web-app, calendar

I'm trying to figure out why a meeting would appear in Outlook (via Exchange) but not in Outlook Web Access.  Exchange and OWA are on two different servers, but the OWA server is just a front-end server.  I would think they'd both look at the same mailstore and show the same entries.

Any thoughts on how to start troubleshooting this?

We're using Exchange 2003 and Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that the mail profile or OST file is corrupted.  I would delete the mail profile and create a new one on the user's PC.

Comment: I tried this and haven't heard anything from the user since.  No news is good news, right?  This seems to make the most sense to me so I've marked it as the correct answer.  Note that intermittent issues like this one make it hard to know if we've truly fixed the problem or not.